# How to include search or fiter function in multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

guys, I require help its related to my HTML. The problem is that I have three pages with individual simple java search function in them, which only searches the specific page. so, is there any way I can implement search or filter function to work simultaneously across all pages. Lastly, I am kinda new so please explain in detail. Thanks in advance

here is the type of search function I have included:
`<li class="searchbox"><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Instantly Search This Page" title="" class="search"></li>`

Java bit:

````
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: `Java` !== `JavaScript`

Comment: Btw is there any framework that you're using to supply common HTML code across the pages?

Comment: thanks for the comment, no i am just using same code for each page.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is you want to keep a common function which you can use accross all pages. You can move the code you mentioned above to a separate js file. Then you can import that common code file to your desired js file like below-

```
import { searchFunction } from './search.js';
```

In search.js

```
export function searchFunction() {
  //Search logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sumit Sinha for the reply, I have java code mentioned in my main question separate in a file, which is then linked to html files.  like this  `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script> ` .  So would your method still work?